# Form validation for password in angular

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have some form with username and password. I have no problem with username but when i set for password name attribute i see strange view with placeholders in both username and password.
I've tried to find in google examples with validation of password but i was surprised to find only custom solutions with directives. Are there no built in solutions for validation of password field like for other fields?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styleAdmin.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="appLogin" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <form name="frmLogin" novalidate>
        <div id="loginBox">
            <div class="lineBox">
                <span class="label">Username</span>
                <input type="text"   name="username" ng-model="user.username" ng-required="true"  ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="8" ng-pattern="/[0-9a-z]/i">
                <span class="error-message" ng-show="frmLogin.username.$dirty&& frmLogin.username.$error" ng-hide="frmLogin.username.$dirty&& frmLogin.username.$valid">
                    The Username is Mandatory
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="lineBox">
                <span class="label">Password</span>
                <input type="password"  name="psd" ng-model="user.password" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="8" ng-pattern="/[0-9a-z]/i">
                <span class="error-message" ng-show="frmLogin.psd.$dirty&&frmLogin.psd.$error" ng-hide="frmLogin.psd.$dirty&& frmLogin.psd.$valid">
                    The password is Mandatory
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="lineBox">
                <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" ng-disabled="frmLogin.$invalid" ng-click="submitLogin()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
       var appAdmin=angular.module('appLogin',[]);
       appAdmin.controller(function($scope,loginService){
       $scope.user={};
       $scope.submitLogin=function(){
       }
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your username & password inputs have the same min / max / pattern values (which are relevant for password only of course)

Comment: After defining the controller properly, and removing the dependency on the unexisting loginService, it works as I expect it to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/6z9uILmWjYo2cipzBF0w?p=preview. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I understand now what a problem. I use wamp server and when i upload my application i see in username and password fields the values for wamp. Why is it happen? (and thanks for quick answers)

Comment: Well, probably because you saved these credentials in the browser, or with a browser extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You should remove the `ng-hide` from error-message span. Since you already have `ng-show` with a valid expression there is no need for `ng-hide`.

If I understood your question correctly. I thing you have a problem with browser auto-filling saved username & password to your fields. If may try putting `autocomplete="off"` on your input fields. But if you are using chrome it is useless. Since chrome has no option to stop auto-filling of username and password. Still there is a workaround for the issue. You can put the dummy username & password fields in you form and hide them by-default.

```
<input type="text" name="username" ng-hide="true">
<input type="text" name="password" ng-hide="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes. The problem is because of chrome. In explorer it works

Comment: Try putting those dummy input fields at the start of your form. The autofill problem with chrome will be solved by this

Comment: Wow, it works! What a trick! Yo say that the dummy fields has been autocompleted by chrome coockies and my real fields are empty when they are prinstine! Excelent solution!